# Trato de ejecutar mi app Flask y me sale este error

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ubern\Desktop\M.O.A.A\JV.py", line 2, in <module>
    from site import Product
ImportError: cannot import name 'Product' from 'site' (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site.py)
```

Comment: Revisa la estructura de tu proyecto. Sin verla más no puedo decir

Comment: No somos adivinos. Edita la pregunta y agrega la información relevante, según lo que has investigado hasta ahora. ¿Has investigado, cierto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Tienes un fichero llamado `site.py` formando parte de tu proyecto, dentro del cual defines la clase `Producto`?

Parece que python en lugar de importar el tuyo, está importando [el que viene con la librería estándar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).

Una posible solución es utilizar import relativos, es decir, cambiar tu código  por:

```
from .site import Product
```

El `.` delante de `site` indica que es un import relativo (a la ruta del paquete). No obstante para que funcione tu código ha de tener estructura de paquete, lo que implica contar con un archivo llamado `__init__.py` (aunque esté vacío).

Otra solución, más sencilla y quizás incluso más razonable, es que cambies de nombre a tu módulo `site.py` para evitar colisiones con paquetes de la biblioteca estándar.